# Laptop screen flickering

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, monitor

I'm having problems with my laptop screen glitching on Ubuntu 20.04. I had this issue while back, reinstalling graphics card drivers didn't help and I ended up reinstalling the whole system. Unfortunately, the problem is back and I really do not want to reinstall my system again.

The problem is only with laptop's screen. External screen is fine and not affected by this issue. Interestingly the frequency of those glitches seems to be related to CPU load e.g. when I'm compiling code the glitching is more severe.

My laptop is Lenovo Legion Y740 with graphics card GeForce RTX 2070 Max-Q running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS.

Switching to Nouveau display driver fixes the problem, but of course I would like to use NVidia's driver.

What can I do to trouble shoot this problem?

[image]

[image]